# iOS: Faster way to format html text to attributed text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a method to format html text to attributed text with the following. However, this method is painfully slow. Is there a way to achieve this much faster?

```
self.textLbl.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:    [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                                              options:@{     NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType
                                                                                         } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: "this method is painfully slow" Really? That's not my experience. What's your evidence for that?

Comment: Also, you are not formatting as plain text; you are formatting as attributed text, which is not plain at all — it has styles.

Comment: if you are using UIWebView you can get innerHTML text by using javascript like: [yourwebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"documentdocument.getElementById('htmlElementID').innerHTML""]